# Dynamic TextFormField within a DataCell => (PaginatedDataTable)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem that when I create a TextFormField inside a DataCell it does not support placing a controller, that is, if I put a controller or even a focusnode, all the TextFormField in the table, which in theory are the same, will be typed together or always take the last one, it varies a lot.

Look at the code I'm doing:

```
DataCell(
            TextFormField(
              autofocus: true,
              inputFormatters: [
                new LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(6),
              ],
              style: TextStyle(color: context.read<DadosAcesso>().color),
              initialValue: row.quantidade,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              onChanged: (text) {
                txt = text;
                updateProdutoQtde(text, index, row.codbarras);
              },
              onEditingComplete: (){
                context.read<DadosAcesso>().search = false;
                context.read<DadosAcesso>().focusBusca.requestFocus();
              },
            ),
        ),
```

I tried using the provider there to see if it helped but it stayed the same, I believe I would have to do something with the index of the table, like creating a TextFormField that contains the index, the key will not be possible to use the index, because the index is int.

Comment: Where do you instantiate the controller? Can you provide more details?

Comment: Hello, if I use a controller, the problem is that the same thing will always be entered in all lines of the table, so I can't use the controller, it happens the same when I use focusnode.

Comment: You should create more than one instance of controller. I asked you about controller because I needed to understand how you create it and use it in your code